# How do I interpret multiple meetings with a potential research advisor?

Tags: phd, advisor

I have had one meeting with a potential research advisor that went really well. They want to touch base again and go over my work experience that is applicable to my research interests before I apply. How do I interpret this? Is this a good thing to have multiple meetings? I know they are considering multiple applicants for the position.

Info: this is a small department, and the advisor also serves as the head of the department. Any insight into how that would play into admissions is also welcome!

Comment: A good sign at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is, most likely, a good sign. If they weren't interested at all, they wouldn't want to spend time in another meeting with you, just to reject you afterwards.

The advisor being the head of the department can mean anything or nothing, so don't read to much into that.